# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Exception

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I tried to define prefix of signing in user, but I got this exception `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`. The thing is django cannot find user Student and Parent(Exception Value: User has no student)

I want to render different templates according to user's type

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prefix = 't'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent', null=True)
    prefix = 's'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name


class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prefix = 'p'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name
```

views.py

```
def sign_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user_login = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user_login)
            if user_login.student.prefix == 'S':
                return render(request, 's.html')
            if user_login.teacher.prefix == 'T':
                return render(request, 't.html')
            if user_login.parent.prefix == 'P':
                return render(request, 'p.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'error': True})
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 20, 2017 - 21:43:51
Django version 1.11.1, using settings 'e_diary.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[20/May/2017 21:43:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 983
Internal Server Error: /sign_in/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\e_diary\electronic_diary\views.py", line 29, in sign_in
    if user_login.teacher.prefix == 'T':
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 406, in __get__
    self.related.get_accessor_name()
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no teacher.
[20/May/2017 21:44:02] "POST /sign_in/ HTTP/1.1" 500 70872
```

Comment: Show your models

Comment: @SakeBolatbek - Screenshots of your code is usually frowned upon on StackOverflow. Just copy paste your code in the question. If you run into formatting issues, we can fix that for you.Also, take some time to think about specifics of your problem - what issue you are facing, what is the stacktrace, and what is the desired outcome. This way, you can get a better response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a related_name to the field user in the Student, Teacher tables like this,

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='student')
```

Also, you need to make sure that for a user , the corresponding student, parent, model is created.

Also, you are checking the prefix to an upper case letter, where in your model they are lower case. Python is strictly case-sensitive.

I think you need to change the if statement too,

```
try:
    if user_login.student.prefix == 'S'
        return render(request, 's.html')
except:
    try:
        if user_login.teacher.prefix == 'T'
            return render(request, 't.html')
    except:
        if user_login.parent.prefix == 'P':
            return render(request, 'p.html')
```

Because, the way in your view, every **if statement** is encountered during the view. Then if the user is Teacher, then it has no student object. Then, Django raises error. So better is to use a try-except combination for the purpose.

Also, from your code, I came up with a suggestion about Student, Teacher, Parent models.
You could use a single Model Profile, with two flags is_teacher, is_parent and a default null ForeignKey field, which is set only if the is_parent flag is True, rather than repeatedly creating tables in the database.
But, this is only a suggestion, as in your approach the Student, Teacher, Parent can be distinguished easily, though it takes up more storage space.

Comment: Can you post your full stack trace?

Comment: How to handle, if the user is nither student nor teacher nor parent.